# Observable chaining in HTTP requests

Tags: asynchronous, angular

I need to inject some HTTP request before each GET. HTTP service requires Observable on return, but before I return it I need to wait on finish of Promise. It looks something like that:

```
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

    ...

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        somePromise()
            .success(() => {
                // now I can return Observable object - super.get(url, otpions)
             });
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that since you override `get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>` method, you can't call the `super` one.

One of the solutions would be to create a service wrapping `Http` and adding your needs, and then use this service as like you are using `http`.

example:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        somePromise()
            .success(() => {
                        return this.http.get(url, options);
        });
    }
}
```